# Fundamental Group of small Zariski open set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $Y$ be an integral affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $K$ be its function field. How to find a sufficiently small Zariski open set of $Y$ such that it is isomorphic to $K(\pi,1)$? Here $\pi$ is the absolute Galois group of $K$.

This statement is from the Galois Cohomology of SGA 4.5.

> On sait qu’il existe des ouverts de Zariski arbitrairement petits qui pour la topologie classique sont des $K(\pi, 1)$. On ne sera donc pas surpris si l’on considère Spec(K) lui-même comme un $K(\pi, 1)$, étant le groupe fondamental (au sens algébrique) de X, autrement dit le groupe de Galois de $\overline{K} /K$,
>   où $\overline{K}$ est clôture séparable de $K$.

Comment: This is proved in SGA 4, ch. XI. These open subsets are called "bons voisinages", see Variante 4.6 at the end of the chapter.